# Como fazer Push Notification para iOS? (preferencialmente usando C#)

Tags: apache-cordova, apple-push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Já consigo enviar push notification para Android. Levando em consideração que já possuo todas as chaves, token do dispositivo e certificados, como é possível enviar um push notification para o iOS?

Vi em alguns lugares que o payload para iOS é diferente do Android. Estou usando GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) e configurei a conta (com os certificados) no site do Firebase conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: Configuração do app para iOS no Firebase]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a enviar um push notification para dispositivo iOS por favor? Se souber em C#, melhor ainda, mas pode ser em qualquer linguagem que já ajuda.

Comment: Eu também tive esse problema no inicio, fui a ver e era dos certificados e da compilação da app, tinha usado o phonegap e o openssl para gerar os certificados... Quando passar a app para o mac e fiz export dos certificados por lá, tudo ficou resolvido... acho que a apple deve de ter mudado algo e agora só é possível fazer isso com um mac

Comment: Meus certificados estão corretos. Tanto que já fiz um teste no site http://pushtry.com/ e funcionou.

Comment: Cara, não sei se ajuda ou se você conhece, mas da uma olhada: http://caiquedourado.com.br/guia-notificacoes-push-para-ecommerce/ ou direto no site: onesignal.com mas se você mesmo quer criar, então desculpe essa resposta, mas acho que pode te dar uma ideia de como fazer, talvez.

Comment: @JáderCarvalhodeMedeiros e tentaste fazer o push para iOS? Recebeste a notificação quando foi pelo site?

Comment: @JoãoSilva Eu fiz o PUSH para iOS através do site que mencionei e funcionou sim. Recebi corretamente no dispositivo.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Não ajuda porque são exemplos de PUSH para navegador e são APIs tercerizadas. Preciso comunicar diretamente com o APNs (Apple Push Notification service).

Comment: Instala o Postman e faz um post com estes dados: https://pastebin.com/rD6u0a8S em baixo diz se foi sucessfull ou não e se não foi diz o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema usando esse código em C# abaixo:

```
public static void EnviarNotificacaoPush(string tokeDispositivo, string mensagem, string caminhoCertificado, string senhaCertificado)
{
    using (var certificado = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoCertificado), senhaCertificado))
    {
        var enderecoPushApple = certificado.FriendlyName.StartsWith("Apple Development") ? "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" : "gateway.push.apple.com";
        using (var clientTcp = new TcpClient(enderecoPushApple, 2195))
        {
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(clientTcp.GetStream()))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(enderecoPushApple, new X509Certificate2Collection(certificado), SslProtocols.Default, false);
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
                    {
                        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { aps = new { alert = mensagem } });
                        writer.Write(new byte[] { 0, 0, 32 }.Concat(HexToData(tokeDispositivo)).Concat(new byte[] { 0, (byte)payload.Length }).ToArray());
                        writer.Write(payload.ToCharArray());
                        writer.Flush();
                        sslStream.Write(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        sslStream.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static byte[] HexToData(string hexString)
{
    if (hexString.Length % 2 == 1)
        hexString = '0' + hexString;
    var data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        data[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: @diegofm Eu usei a área de respostas para postar a minha resposta. Enquanto esperava alguém da comunidade me ajudar, felizmente encontrei a solução e resolvi publicá-la para compartilhar com os colegas da comunidade.

Comment: Jader, ah sim, perdoe-me, pensei que era um complemento :)